# Customising the buffer name of a dired buffer

Tags: emacs, buffer, dired

I'd like to have one single dired buffer alive at any time, and I want to be able to bring it to the front with a particular hot key.  However, in order to do that, I would need the dired buffer to always have the same name.  But the buffer name changes every time a new directory is loaded.  Is there a way to tell dired to not change the name?  I tried tweaking the reading and loading hooks but it didn't work.

Alternatively, is there a command to bring forward an existing dired buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not find a buffer that `(eq major-mode 'dired-mode)` instead of trying to keep the same name?  Take a look at this kill all dired mode buffers in this link -- you can modify it:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers  Maybe put in there a catch found throw found.

Comment: Prepending "dired:" to the normal buffer name would allow to use regexps to identify any dired buffer while still maintaining the association with the directory. I would be very interested in this option...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't want to do that. Some Dired features depend on the buffer name being associated with the directory.

A better approach might be to have a command that switches to the only Dired buffer, since you will be having only one at a time.

```
(defun switch-to-dired-buffer ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (let ((dbufs  (cl-remove-if-not
                 (lambda (bf)
                   (with-current-buffer bf
                     (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)))
                 (buffer-list))))
    (switch-to-buffer (car dbufs))))
```

You can also get fancier and prompt for which Dired buffer if there is more than one etc.

Answer (score 0):

Possible drawbacks notwithstanding, the following code does what you want:

```lisp
(setq dired-default-buffer-name "*Dired*")

(defun dired-set-default-buffer-name ()
  "Set name of Dired buffer to `dired-default-buffer-name'.

If there already is a buffer with that name, kill it first."
  (when (get-buffer dired-default-buffer-name)
    (kill-buffer (get-buffer dired-default-buffer-name)))
  (rename-buffer dired-default-buffer-name))

(defadvice dired (after dired-set-default-buffer-name activate compile)
  "Set name of Dired buffer to default name when launching Dired."
  (dired-set-default-buffer-name))

(defadvice dired-find-file (after dired-set-default-buffer-name activate compile)
  "Set name of Dired buffer to default name when entering a subdirectory."
  (when (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
    (dired-set-default-buffer-name)))

(defun dired-switch-to-default-buffer ()
  "Bring up default Dired buffer."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer dired-default-buffer-name))

;; Set up global key binding for bringing up default Dired buffer:
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-d") 'dired-switch-to-default-buffer)
```

Note that if you use `ido-mode` you will need to replace `dired` with `ido-dired` in the first `defadvice`. Also, `dired-switch-to-default-buffer` doesn't check if you have already launched Dired; you will have to modify that function a little if you want it to work in that case as well (e.g. by opening Dired in some default location).

---

**EDIT**

If you find that you are in fact using functionality that depends on the name of the Dired buffer being associated with the directory displayed, you can add this:

```lisp
(setq dired-original-buffer-name nil)

(defun dired-restore-original-name ()
  (rename-buffer dired-original-buffer-name))

(defun dired-toggle-name ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq (buffer-name) dired-default-buffer-name)
      (dired-restore-original-name)
    (dired-set-default-buffer-name)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-t") 'dired-toggle-name)
```

... and modify `dired-set-default-buffer-name` to look like this:

```lisp
(defun dired-set-default-buffer-name ()
  "Set name of Dired buffer to `dired-default-buffer-name'.

If there already is a buffer with that name, kill it first."
  (when (get-buffer dired-default-buffer-name)
    (kill-buffer (get-buffer dired-default-buffer-name)))
  (setq dired-original-buffer-name (buffer-name)) ;; Keep track of original
                                                  ;; buffer name so we can
                                                  ;; restore it
  (rename-buffer dired-default-buffer-name))
```

This will allow you to toggle between the original name of the Dired buffer and the default name by issuing the associated key binding (currently: <kbd>C-c C-t</kbd>, but you can of course modify that to suit your needs).